# Which workout to do 1st?

Tags: exercise-technique, home-exercise

I am a fitness enthusiastic person. I don't go to gym but choose to workout at home. So that I select some exercise like push ups,biceps curl,tricep dips,squat,crunch,dumbel row each side, plank,sit ups . But I am confused what of these exercise should do first and what to next??

Comment: That would depend upon your goals and what you hope to accomplish.

Comment: @rrirower I want to build muscle and reduce belly fat. Now tell me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said you want to reduce fat, you need to focus on what you are eating first. Your energy expenditure should be more than your calorie intake. There's no specific guideline on what to do first. Also, there's no exercise to reduce belly fat. You need to have a overall reduction of your body fat.

Regarding workout, you need to mix cardio and weight training in right proportion, to build mass and reduce fat. As you said you workout at home, I'd suggest going out for a run would be a good cardio, or skipping the rope. Carry on with your usual workout, but divide it into parts, and do one part per day, like arms on a day, chest on the other, legs on another day and accordingly, to give your muscles some recovery time to grow.